# Как в WPF передавать данные между страницами?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, page

Есть приложение на WPF в на некоторых страницах есть TextBox по клику на которые должна появляться форма подобна калькулятору, где мы можем вводить данные нажимать на ней кнопку OK и данные и этой формы должны отображаться сразу в TextBox, как на отдельной страница этого "Калькулятора" можно получать объект именно того TextBox по которому был произведен клик?
[image: Так выглядит представление]

Элемент "Калькулятор" добавлено на страницу с помощью Frame.
Подскажите я новичок может я не правильно все делаю?

Comment: Какой MVVM фреймворк используете?

Comment: Понятия не имею, на работе дали задание это сделать, дали на половину написанный проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не пользуетесь каким-либо Фреймворком, то в качестве посредника вполне может выступить само окно программы или активный в данный момент `UserControl`. Привожу пример где в качестве посредника выступает кодбихайнд окна программы.

[image: Пример работы программы]

Типа калькулятор:) PageCalc.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxInput" Text="{Binding InputCalc, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" Margin="10" />
        <Button Content="1" Margin="10"
                Command="{Binding NumberInputCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Button Content="2" Margin="10"
                Command="{Binding NumberInputCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Button Content="3" Margin="10" 
                Command="{Binding NumberInputCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Button Content="OK" Margin="10" Command="{Binding CalcOkCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Его `ViewModel` CalcViewModel.cs

```
public class CalcViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    //ctor
    public CalcViewModel()
    {

    }

    //Properties
    public IMainWindowCodeBehind CodeBehind { get; set; }

    private string _InputCalc;
    public string InputCalc
    {
        get { return _InputCalc; }
        set
        {
            _InputCalc = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(InputCalc)));
        }
    }

    //Commands

    private RelayCommand<string> _NumberInputCommand;
    public RelayCommand<string> NumberInputCommand
    {
        get { return _NumberInputCommand = _NumberInputCommand ??
                new RelayCommand<string>(OnNumberInput); }
    }
    private void OnNumberInput(string number)
    {
        InputCalc += number;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Нажатие кнопки ОК во фрейме калькулятор
    /// </summary>
    private RelayCommand _CalcOkCommand;
    public RelayCommand CalcOkCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _CalcOkCommand = _CalcOkCommand ??
              new RelayCommand(OnCalcOk);
        }
    }
    private void OnCalcOk()
    {
        CodeBehind.CloseCalcPage();
    }

}
```

Окно программы MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Leak Size:" />
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLeakSize" Text="{Binding LeakSize}"
                     Width="150" Margin="10,0"
                     GotFocus="textBox_GotFocus"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Other Size:" />
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxOtherSize" Text="{Binding OtherSize}"
                     Width="150" Margin="10,0"
                     GotFocus="textBox_GotFocus" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="frame" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" BorderBrush="LimeGreen" BorderThickness="2"
           NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</Grid>
```

Его `ViewModel` MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }

    //Properties

    private string _LeakSize;
    public string LeakSize
    {
        get { return _LeakSize; }
        set
        {
            _LeakSize = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LeakSize)));
        }
    }

    private string _OtherSize;
    public string OtherSize
    {
        get { return _OtherSize; }
        set
        {
            _OtherSize = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OtherSize)));
        }
    }

}
```

Ну и самое главное - кодбихайнд окна программы

```
public interface IMainWindowCodeBehind
{
    void CloseCalcPage();
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMainWindowCodeBehind
{
    //
    private MainViewModel _MainVM;
    private CalcViewModel _CalcVM;

    private TextBox _ActiveTextBox;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;

        //загрузка вьюмодел, установка контекста данных
        _MainVM = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _MainVM;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //пустая страница во фрейм
        this.frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("PageEmpty.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Событие получения фокуса каким-то TextBox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //ссылка на редактируемый textbox
        _ActiveTextBox = sender as TextBox;

        //выключаем
        textBoxLeakSize.IsEnabled = false;
        textBoxOtherSize.IsEnabled = false;

        //загрузка страницы и ее вьюмодел, установка контекста данных
        PageCalc page = new PageCalc();
        _CalcVM = new CalcViewModel();
        page.DataContext = _CalcVM;
        //даем ссылку на этот кодбихайнд, чтобы можно было вызвать CloseCalcPage()
        _CalcVM.CodeBehind = this;

        this.frame.NavigationService.Navigate(page);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Метод вызываемый из CalcViewModel
    /// Закрытие страницы калькулятора
    /// </summary>
    public void CloseCalcPage()
    {
        //включаем
        textBoxLeakSize.IsEnabled = true;
        textBoxOtherSize.IsEnabled = true;

        if (_ActiveTextBox != null)
        {
            if (_ActiveTextBox.Name == textBoxLeakSize.Name)
            {
                //изменяем значение, через свойство вьюмодел
                _MainVM.LeakSize = _CalcVM.InputCalc;
            }
            else
            {
                _MainVM.OtherSize = _CalcVM.InputCalc;
            }
        }
        _ActiveTextBox = null;
        _CalcVM = null;

        this.frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("PageEmpty.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }  

}
```

Обратите внимание, что при нажатии на ОК в калькуляторе происходит вызов метода `CloseCalcPage()` из кодбихайнд окна программы.

P.S. класс `RelayCommand` или еще можно встретить в интернетах `DelegateCommand` это вариации на тему реализации интерфейска `ICommand`
вот например можете взять и использовать эту

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    Action _TargetExecuteMethod;
    Func<bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    #region ICommand Members

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return _TargetCanExecuteMethod();
        }
        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Beware - should use weak references if command instance lifetime is longer than lifetime of UI objects that get hooked up to command
    // Prism commands solve this in their implementation
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    Action<T> _TargetExecuteMethod;
    Func<T, bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T,bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() 
    {
         CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
    }
    #region ICommand Members

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            T tparm = (T)parameter;
            return _TargetCanExecuteMethod(tparm);
        }
        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Beware - should use weak references if command instance lifetime is longer than lifetime of UI objects that get hooked up to command
    // Prism commands solve this in their implementation
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod((T)parameter);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: а как в CalcViewModel.cs реализован класс RelayCommand ?

Comment: @IvanProdaiko смотрите P.S. я добавил класс `RelayCommand`

Answer (score 2):

Обычно, в рамках паттерна MVVM каждый `TextBox` связывается с соответствующим свойством `string` во View Model, и этого достаточно. Но ваши `TextBox` обладают дополнительной возможностью – они умеют вызывать калькулятор по клику. Поэтому, у каждого `TextBox` должна быть своя View Model с текстом и командой вызова калькулятора.

У калькулятора, в свою очередь, есть своя View Model со свойством `Text` и командами `OkCommand` и `CancelCommand`, не считая всего остального.

Возникает вопрос – а как, собственно, наладить коммуникацию между двумя View Model, а также View Model и View, при этом не создавая жестких связей между классами? Для этого используется [паттерн Посредник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). В моем примере я использую библиотеку [MVVM Light Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) и её класс `Messenger`.

В итоге, View Model для текстовых полей выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class TextBoxViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _text;

    public TextBoxViewModel()
    {
        ShowCalculatorCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowCalculator);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { Set(ref _text, value); }
    }

    public ICommand ShowCalculatorCommand { get; }

    private void ShowCalculator()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Send(new NotificationMessage<string>(Text, "ShowCalculator"));

        // Слушаем нотификацию "SubmitCalculator".
        MessengerInstance.Register<NotificationMessage<string>>(this, message =>
        {
            if (message.Notification == "SubmitCalculator")
            {
                Text = message.Content;
            }
        });

        // Слушаем нотификацию "CloseCalculator".
        MessengerInstance.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, message =>
        {
            if (message.Notification == "CloseCalculator")
            {
                // Калькулятор закрыт - отписываемся от нотификаций.
                MessengerInstance.Unregister(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в обработчике команды `ShowCalculatorCommand` мы генерируем нотификацию "ShowCalculator" и прикрепляем к ней начальный текст. Мы также подписываемся на нотификации "SubmitCalculator" и "CloseCalculator", чтобы принять измененный калькулятором текст и отписаться от нотификаций после закрытия калькулятора соответственно.

Нотификацию "ShowCalculator" обработает соответствующий View, который занимается созданием новых окон/фреймов (здесь и далее я использую отдельные окна, но в вашем случае – это будут отдельные фреймы):

```
// В обработчике события Loaded главного окна.
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<string>>(this, message =>
{
    if (message.Notification == "ShowCalculator")
    {
        var window = new CalculatorWindow
        {
            DataContext = new CalculatorViewModel { Text = message.Content }
        };

        window.Show();
    }
});
```

В свою очередь, `CalculatorWindow` должно перехватить нотификацию "CloseCalculator" и закрыть себя:

```
// В обработчике события Loaded окна с калькулятором.
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, message =>
{
    if (message.Notification == "CloseCalculator")
    {
        Close();
    }
});
```

И напоследок View Model калькулятора:

```
public class CalculatorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _text;

    public CalculatorViewModel()
    {
        OkCommand = new RelayCommand(Ok);
        CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(Cancel);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { Set(ref _text, value); }
    }

    public ICommand OkCommand { get; }
    public ICommand CancelCommand { get; }

    private void Ok()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Send(new NotificationMessage<string>(Text, "SubmitCalculator"));
        MessengerInstance.Send(new NotificationMessage("CloseCalculator"));
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Send(new NotificationMessage("CloseCalculator"));
    }

    // ... (остальная логика калькулятора)
}
```

Думаю, что разметка View достаточно тривиальна, так что оставляю её за вами.