# Привязка объекта класса Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть отдельный класс PicContainer с полем типа Bitmap. Как можно привязать это поле к контролу "image"?
Код класса PicContainer:

```
 class PicContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public Bitmap image;
        public Bitmap Image { get { return image;} set { image = value; } }

        public String text = "Превет";
        public String Text { get { return text;} set { text = value; } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Главная форма:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PicContainer SimpleClass = new PicContainer();
            SimpleClass.Image = new Bitmap("1.jpg");
        }
    }
```

Код XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="imageControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:imageControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image x:Name="Pic" Margin="5" Source="{Binding ElementName=PicContainer ,Path=SimpleClass.Image}"></Image>
            <Button x:Name="Button"  Content="{Binding Path=Class.Text}" Click="Button_Click" Height="20"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Результат 0. Как нужно изменить XAML разметку, чтобы картинка загрузилась?

Comment: `set { image = value; } }` а где вы тут вызываете OnPropertyChanged()?

Comment: И как можно исправить?

Comment: В сеттере свойства нужно вызвать вашу OnPropertyChanged(), чтобы сообщить UI, что значение этого свойства изменилось.

Comment: вот я [отвечал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634211/222542) человеку и сделал для него каркас приложения, и хотя там нет картинки, но общий смысл работы со свойствами вам должен стать понятен.

Comment: @Zurus: А что это у вас за `Bitmap`? Это случайно не Winform'овский `System.Drawing.Bitmap`?

Comment: Да, это он. Для WPF он не подходит?

Comment: Нужен [BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: Используйте конвертер для преобразования