# WPF MVVM. Замена одного представления на другое

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Недавно начал разбираться с wpf и шаблоном mvvm и появилась проблема, решение которой никак не приходит ко мне в голову. 
Есть главное окно, в котором есть UserControl с формой входа и кнопкой "войти". 
Мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку UserControl, c кнопкой "войти" и формой входа, заменялся на другой UserControl. 
Была идея как-то это реализовать через команды, но ViewModel не должен знать о View, поэтому я в ступоре. 
Подскажите как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Подобный же [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634211/222542) уже был

Answer (score 1):

Идея о том, что вам нужна *команда*, правильная: авторизация пользователя — это часть flow приложения. Вопрос лишь в том, как сделать так, чтобы изменения в VM отображались во View.

Обычно такое делается при помощи `DataTemplate`'ов. Давайте положим в `MainVM` свойство (например) `CurrentActionVM` типа `object` (не забудьте реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged` или чего-то равносильного). Также заведём две маленькие VM: `LoginVM` и `LogoutVM`. Они будут соответствовать состоянию, когда нужна авторизация, и состоянию, когда авторизация произошла.

В начале вы говорите

```
LoginVM loginVM = new LoginVM();
LogoutVM logoutVM = new LogoutVM();
```

```
CurrentActionVM = loginVM;
```

В команде, которая выполняется при нажатию на кнопку, вы просто говорите

```
CurrentActionVM = logoutVM;
```

С VM-частью всё. Теперь View.

А в нём тоже всё просто. Вы в ресурсах окна объявляете, как будут отображаться ваши VM:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginVM}">
        <LoginUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LogoutVM}">
        <LogoutUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Теперь в той точке, где вам нужно отобразить `UserControl`'ы, вы пишете просто

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentActionVM}"/>
```

Всё!

Comment: Можно и так, конечно, но как быть если нужно передавать между вьюмоделями рабочий экземпляр какого-то класса?

Comment: @Bulson: А это внутренняя VM-проблема. Посмотрите сами, у вас есть два класса, они хотят обмениваться данными, как это сделать? Тривиальная проблема, согласитесь.

Comment: Ну как тривиальная? Здесь может быть много разных подходов начиная от наблюдателя и кончая простой передачей ссылки через конструктор.

Comment: @Bulson: Ну да. Но это как бы известная проблема, решаемая сотней различных способов. Она не специфична для VM-классов.

Answer (score 0):

В WindowMVVM

```
    <UserControl Name="UC" Content="{Binding Path=SelectWindowViewModel}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LoginViewModel}">
            <Views:LoginView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:RegistrationViewModel}">
            <Views:RegistrationView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel WindowMVVMViewModel

```
    public sealed class WindowMVVMViewModel : ViewModelBase , IObjectWindowMVVM
{

    public WindowMVVMViewModel Parent { get; set; }

    public WindowMVVMViewModel()
    {
        this.SelectWindowViewModel = new StartWindowViewModel() { Parent = this };
    }

    private IObjectWindowMVVM _selectWindowViewModel;
    public IObjectWindowMVVM SelectWindowViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectWindowViewModel;
        }
        set
        {

            _selectWindowViewModel = value;
            _selectWindowViewModel.Parent = this;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectWindowViewModel");
        }
    }
    public void SSS()
    {

    }
}
```

UserControl который загружаем по дефолту

```
    public class StartWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase , IObjectWindowMVVM
{
    public WindowMVVMViewModel Parent { get; set; }

    private string _titleProgramm;
    public StartWindowViewModel()
    {
        TitleProgramms = "INFOTEK";
    }

    //public ICommand FirstViewCommand { get; private set; }
    //private void Pass_to_second_ViewModel()
    //{
    //    Parent.SelectWindowViewModel =(IObject) new LoginViewModel();
    //   // Debug.WriteLine("OK");
    //}
    public ICommand ChangeLoginView
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                this.Parent.SelectWindowViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            });
        }
    }
    public ICommand ChangeRegistration
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                Parent.SelectWindowViewModel = new RegistrationViewModel();
            });
        }
    }


    public string TitleProgramms
    {
        get { return _titleProgramm; }
        set { _titleProgramm = value; }
    }
}
```

Интерфейс IObjectWindowMVVM

```
    public interface IObjectWindowMVVM
{
    WindowMVVMViewModel Parent { get; set; }

}
```

Ну и по вызову команд ChangeLoginView и ChangeRegistration грузим наш UserContol