# Переключение страниц в wpf по архитектуре mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем доброго времени суток. Моя проблема заключается в следующем, как реализовать в WPF переключение между страницами используя MVVM. Переключение должно осуществлять по нажатию кнопки, расположенных слева на изображении.Страниц будет всего лишь шесть, как и кнопок.  [image: Окно]

Comment: надо было поиском воспользоваться: [вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/644129/222542), [ещё](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634211/222542).

Comment: Есть 2 варианта или NavigationService и Pages или UserControls и ContentControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже указывал в комментариях на пример своего ответа [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634211/222542). Может такой вариант и представляется кому-то рабоче-крестьянским способом, в особенности для любителей девственно чистого кодбихайнд, но я считаю его вполне годным и, самое главное, простым и быстрым в реализации. Ладно, это лирика.

Вот вам другой вариант,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с рефлексией, все дела, как у четких пацанов...:) Это не мой мопед, я чисто его сп... подсмотрел в проекте [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).
Подход довольно интересный, кстати.

Создаем вот такой интерфейс

```
public interface IModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Название выводимое в меню
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Ссылка на вьюшку
    /// </summary>
    UserControl UserInterface { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Отключение текущей вьюшки, для вьюмоделей с реализацией IDisposable
    /// </summary>
    void Deactivate();
}
```

Далее для каждой пары View & ViewModel создается еще один класс, который реализует этот интерфейс таким образом:

```
class SeparateDemo : IModule
{
    //наша неразлучная парочка
    private SeparateDemoView view;
    private SeparateDemoViewModel viewModel;

    public string Name => "Вьюшка SeparateDemo";


    public UserControl UserInterface
    {
        get { if (view == null) CreateView(); return view; }
    }

    private void CreateView()
    {
        //загружаем вьюшку
        view = new SeparateDemoView();
        //её вьюмодель
        viewModel = new SeparateDemoViewModel();
        //связываем их между собой
        view.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    public void Deactivate()
    {
        viewModel.Dispose();
        view = null;
    }
}
```

т.е. это такой загрузчик для пары View & ViewModel.
Далее это у нас MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModule, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" 
                      Content="{Binding UserInterface}" />
</Grid>
```

Это её вьюмодель, которая подгружает и отображает нужную вьюшку

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    //ctor
    public MainWindowViewModel(IEnumerable<IModule> modules)
    {
        Modules = modules.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
        if (this.Modules.Count > 0)
        {
            SelectedModule = this.Modules[0];
        }
    }

    //Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Список всех возможных загрузчиков пар View и ViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public List<IModule> Modules { get; private set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Выбранная и загруженная парочка View и ViewModel
    /// </summary>
    private IModule _SelectedModule;
    public IModule SelectedModule
    {
        get { return _SelectedModule; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _SelectedModule) return;
            if (_SelectedModule != null) _SelectedModule.Deactivate();
            _SelectedModule = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedModule)));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserInterface"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// То, что отображает View через ContentPresenter 
    /// </summary>
    public UserControl UserInterface
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedModule == null) return null;
            return SelectedModule.UserInterface;
        }
    }
}
```

А вот теперь самая мякотка - тут без рефлексии не обойтись

```
static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> CreateAllInstancesOf<T>()
    {
        return typeof(ReflectionHelper).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsClass)
            .Select(t => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t));
    }
}
```

Подправляем App.xaml такой строчкой - `Startup="Application_Startup">`
И тогда App.xaml.cs такой

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

        var modules = ReflectionHelper.CreateAllInstancesOf<IModule>();

        var vm = new MainWindowViewModel(modules);
        mainWindow.DataContext = vm;
        mainWindow.Closing += (s, args) => vm.SelectedModule.Deactivate();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Вот и все. Как вариант можно сделать промежуточный класс `abstract class ModuleBase : IModule` и тогда загрузчик пары можно сделать таким

```
class FirstDemo : ModuleBase
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Вьюшка FirstDemo"; }
    }

    protected override UserControl CreateViewAndViewModel()
    {
        return new FirstDemoView() { DataContext = new FirstDemoViewModel() };
    }
}
```

Весь проект целиком можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/KNDqMNFi3GPNKU).

Comment: Ссылки на вьюхи прямо во ViewModel-ах. Зачем тогда MVVM?

Comment: @Raider Вы походу не разобрались в примере, там нет ничего подобного, в чем вы пытаетесь меня упрекнуть.

Comment: `MainWindowViewModel.UserInterface`, `MainWindowViewModel.Modules[...].UserInterface`

Comment: @Raider Да, чёрт, я этого и не заметил. Вы правы в этой `MainWindowViewModel` действительно есть нарушение. Хотя, это можно списать на её "узкую специализацию" по поддержке переключения отображения между другими вьюхами. В остальных ведь такого нет. Но, да, есть косячек, спасибо, что обратили внимание, я в торопях писал и проглядел. Понадеялся на авторитет этого NAudio.

Answer (score 1):

А если организовать чуть чуть иначе?
У меня лично вот как сделано.
В WindowMVVM

```
    <UserControl Name="UC" Content="{Binding Path=SelectWindowViewModel}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LoginViewModel}">
            <Views:LoginView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:RegistrationViewModel}">
            <Views:RegistrationView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel WindowMVVMViewModel

```
    public sealed class WindowMVVMViewModel : ViewModelBase , IObjectWindowMVVM
{

    public WindowMVVMViewModel Parent { get; set; }

    public WindowMVVMViewModel()
    {
        this.SelectWindowViewModel = new StartWindowViewModel() { Parent = this };
    }

    private IObjectWindowMVVM _selectWindowViewModel;
    public IObjectWindowMVVM SelectWindowViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectWindowViewModel;
        }
        set
        {

            _selectWindowViewModel = value;
            _selectWindowViewModel.Parent = this;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectWindowViewModel");
        }
    }
    public void SSS()
    {

    }
}
```

UserControl который загружаем по дефолту

```
    public class StartWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase , IObjectWindowMVVM
{
    public WindowMVVMViewModel Parent { get; set; }

    private string _titleProgramm;
    public StartWindowViewModel()
    {
        TitleProgramms = "INFOTEK";
    }

    //public ICommand FirstViewCommand { get; private set; }
    //private void Pass_to_second_ViewModel()
    //{
    //    Parent.SelectWindowViewModel =(IObject) new LoginViewModel();
    //   // Debug.WriteLine("OK");
    //}
    public ICommand ChangeLoginView
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                this.Parent.SelectWindowViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            });
        }
    }
    public ICommand ChangeRegistration
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                Parent.SelectWindowViewModel = new RegistrationViewModel();
            });
        }
    }


    public string TitleProgramms
    {
        get { return _titleProgramm; }
        set { _titleProgramm = value; }
    }
}
```

Интерфейс IObjectWindowMVVM

```
    public interface IObjectWindowMVVM
{
    WindowMVVMViewModel Parent { get; set; }

}
```

Ну и по вызову команд ChangeLoginView и ChangeRegistration грузим наш UserContol
А у Вас получается методом свитча подставляете пользовательский контролл и отображаете. Только в моем случае кода в три раза меньше и удобней + ни одной строчки в код бихайнде.