# Включить содержимое Page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я создал файл `View/Main/Pages/InfoPage.xaml`и теперь хочу включить его в главное окно

В файле `View/Main/MainView.xaml` я пишу:

```
xmlns:Pages="clr-namespace:HDS.View.Main.Pages"
```

И там же пытаюсь вывести

```
<Pages:InfoPage />
```

Но у меня вылетает исключение на `InitializeComponent`, что я делаю не так?

P.S. Может есть более грамотные пути для включения страниц в модели MVVC?

P.S.2 Правильно ли я сделал что для каждой `Viev` я создаю папку, а в этой папке ещё папк `Pages` для страниц? Куда вообще лучше в структуре проекта помещать страницы в модели MVVC?

Comment: Добавьте содержимое сообщения об исключении, скорее всего ошибка в разметке `InfoPage.xaml`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634115/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-wpf-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0

Comment: ...дубликат?(3 символа нужно...)

Comment: Вы делаете неправильно. Вы не должны включать Page внутрь других элементов. Для создания повторно используемой разметки применяйте UserControl.