# Хочу сделать переключения между меню. Как это лучше сделать? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такое меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Играть" появилось это меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я посмотрел [этот ролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZSFY8YdSrA) и понял что использовать Page и Frame, это не совсем то, что я хочу по ряду причин:

-Это скорее вкладки(как в браузере), чем отдельные меню.

-Переключения происходят с помощью кнопок, которые находятся отдельно от Frame, а у меня переход должен быть с страницы на страницу.

Как лучше реализовать то, что я хочу(Если можно посоветуйте какую-то статью или туториал)

Comment: Я же вам уже кидал "альтернативу" и давай пару советов. Вы хоть пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал. Пробовал интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged. Но с помощью него смог лишь добиться изменения цвета фона при нажатии на кнопку. У меня есть главное окно, на нем Frame(я все-таки решил попробовать использовать его). Есть страница "Главное меню". Я не понимаю как из страницы передать информацию об изменении страницы в главное окно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/634211/222542