# MVVM Подменю WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть готовая версия кода, но там нет реализованного подменю, у меня не получается это реализовать, может найдётся кто сможет=)

[image: Образец]

[Ссылка вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634115/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-wpf-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0)
[Ссылка проекта](https://yadi.sk/d/p1BzAvRL3EraxC)

Comment: Будьте более конкретны. Опишите что именно у вас не получилось и какую помощь вы рассчитываете получить.

Comment: То что на скриншоте, верхнее меню переключает UserControl обведённый красной рамкой (это получилось), но как переключаться внутри рамки по этому же методу, с помощью левого меню, обведённое синей рамкой справа. Я не прошу делать с точностью как на скриншоте, а просто доработать тот код, я просто не знаю как это сделать, но сам метод я изучил, но не хватает знаний чтобы расширить. То есть тоже самое только внутри самой UserControl.

Comment: вы должны понять, что никто не будет качать ваш проект и пытаться в нем разбираться и тем более дописывать его для вас. Я бы вам посоветовал вместо ссылок на яндекс диски добавить сюда, прямо в ваш вопрос, минимальный код, который иллюстрирует вашу проблему. Чтобы любой отвечающий мог взглянуть на ваш вопрос, сразу понять где проблема и вам что то посоветовать.

Comment: Я скинул ссылку вопроса, там код расписан, но без этого метода, просто улучшить ту версию ответа.

Comment: Абсолютно так же, забудьте про меню верхнего уровня и сделайте чтобы работаю меню внутри краской рамки так как приведено в том топике. Потом все это вынесите в отдельную вьюху и переключайте ее в окне уже с помощью меню верхнего уровня

Comment: Андрей, я так делаю, но никак работать не хочет, возможно я что то упускаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уверены, что нашли самый простой способ решения своей задачи?

Вроде-как `TabControl` это всё умеет.

```xaml
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
                <TabItem Header="SubTab1"/>
                <TabItem Header="SubTab2"/>
                <TabItem Header="SubTab3"/>
            </TabControl>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2"/>
        <TabItem Header="Tab3"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Осталось только привязать табы к коллекциям, разметить шаблоны, добавить немного стилей для красоты, и готово.

[image: tabcontrol]

**Дополнение**

Чтобы растянуть горизонтальные табы на всю ширину `TabControl`, можно воспользоваться следующим способом, который я подглядел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705815), и немного доработал.

1) Создайте конвертер, добавьте в решение следующий класс

```csharp
public class TabSizeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is int itemsCount && itemsCount > 0 && values[1] is double actualWidth)
        {
            double width = actualWidth / itemsCount;
            return (width <= 1) ? 0 : (width - itemsCount); // минусую по пикселю за каждый таб, чтобы все влезло в одну строку
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

2) Затем добавьте конвертер в ресурсы окна

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TabSizeConverter x:Key="tabSizeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

3) Затем можно подключить этот конвертер к ширине табы, для того чтобы это аффектило только табконтрол с верхним расположением табов, я добавил `Style.Trigger`.

```xaml
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top">
                    <Setter Property="Width">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource tabSizeConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}" Path="Items.Count"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabItem Header="SubTab1"/>
            <TabItem Header="SubTab2"/>
            <TabItem Header="SubTab3"/>
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab3"/>
</TabControl>
```

[image: tabcontrol stretched tabs]

Comment: Да, это конечно проще, я так уже делал, но не знаю как верхнее меню растянуть по центру, как я сделал это с кнопками на скриншоте)

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ а зачем растягивать? У вас окно фиксированного размера? Пункты главного меню сверху фиксированы и не будут изменяться? Мне кажется, достаточно просто стилизации, чтобы у табов не было фона и рамок, и настроить необходимые паддинги для того, чтобы между ними было достаточное расстояние, чтобы всё это подходило под вашу дизайнерскую задумку.

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ посмотрите [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518107/wpf-tabcontrol-styling).

Comment: Я посмотрел, я думаю как сделать вот такое меню https://dragablz.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/materialdesigndemo1.gif без дополнительный пакетов, не нужно отделять окно, нужен только такой стиль.

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ дополнил ответ, думаю это вы искали :)

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ старайтесь писать свои стили в целях самообучения, можно конечно на чужих примерах. А то потом попадете в ситуацию, когда вам нужно что-то где-то в чужих стилях поменять, а вы даже не знаете как оно работает.

Comment: У меня ошибка на эту строку <local:TabSizeConverter x:Key="tabSizeConverter"/> пишу на .NET Framework 3.5; Ошибка: тег "TabSizeConverter" не существует в пространстве имен XML "clr-namespace:WPF" https://ibb.co/WKSmgkP https://ibb.co/pLZdN7W скриншоты моего приложения. Там не TabControl, а обычные кнопки, я не представляю как такое сделать с TabControl=)

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ дизайнер просто не видит добавленный класс, пока вы не выполните сборку. Только после сборки появляется возможность его использовать. Не знаю, почему Microsoft так сделали.

Comment: Всё исправил ошибку, дак вот, как TabControl сделать таким красивым, не где нету гайдов, есть на youtube, но там с использованием пакетов и .NET 4.5. Я кстати вспомнил почему я не хотел использовать TabControl=) скрины: https://ibb.co/hf2FcgK Так как я TabControl скрываю, соответственно я скрываю что внутри него. https://ibb.co/pJq227c

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ `TabItem.Header` - это кнопка, `TabItem.Content` - это содержимое табы. Можно и на то, и на другое навесить `Template`, и хоть картинка, хоть что угодно туда влезет.

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ вам не нужен гайд по `TabControl`, вам нужно научиться использовать `Style`, `DataTemplate` и `ControlTemplate`. Оно одинаково работает со всеми контролами.

Comment: В том то и дело что я учусь на примерах, мне так лучше запоминается, потом переделываю под себя. Я могу скинуть свой проект, чтоб вы могли посмотреть и отредактировать. Потом я буду изучать то что изменили и исправлять, дополнять.

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ ну вот у вас есть уже стиль для `TabItem`, добавьте туда после `</Style.Triggers>` еще один `Setter`, посмотрите, что вам предложит студия, когда вы напишете `Property=`. Используйте **IntelliSense** подсказки, без них очень тяжело жить в WPF, да и вообще где угодно. Начните с задания позрачного `Background`, размера и типа шрифтов, высоты заголовка табы, и так далее. Как научитесь менять стили, найдете, что есть свойство `Template`, которое там же в стилях можно переопределить. Научитесь использовать общие ресурсы: это про `x:Key` и `StaticResource`.

Comment: @ZeroneXYZ ищите гайды по xaml разметке в WPF. Изучив ее возможности вы сможете издеваться :) над любыми контролами, не только над `TabControl`, но и над более сложными контролами типа `TreeView`. Туда еще добавить навык работы с конвертерами и мультиконвертерами (второй из двух в примере выше), и вообще кодить станет ощутимо веселее.